# Is there a way to avoid repetitive compiler warning messages?

Tags: warnings, texniccenter

I use TeXnicCenter, and use the very convenient 'Compilation Results' window (see screenshot below). I have a number of identical warning* messages (not strictly identical of course, as they point to a different position in my LaTeX source).

Is there a way to have the latex compiler ignore or suppress text-identical  warning messages, so that they don't fill my buffer, and so that I can easily notice any other warning messages?

TeXniCenter doesn't seem to provide such a feature, so I am resorting to the latex compiler here.

(*) The origin of the message is that I use math mode in my headings, and the `hyperref` package warns me that it ignores these. *For now*, I don't want to turn off the hyperref package, and i don't want to take out the math symbol in my headings either.

[image: Compilation Results window screenshot]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One solution it to use the `silence` package. According to its documentation it is able to do the following

> This package is designed to ﬁlter out unwanted warnings and error messages. Entire packages (including LaTeX) can be censored, but very speciﬁc messages can be targeted too. TeX’s messages are left untouched.

In this example you can see how it works and suppresses the warning "Token not allowed in a PDF string".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{hyperref}{Token not allowed}     
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{$x_2$}
\end{document}
```

But it would be even better if you use `texorpdfstring` for mathematical formulas in headings

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{\texorpdfstring{$x_2$}{x2}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you care about the document, use variant II (with `\textorpdfstring`)

Comment: THanks for both suggestions, I'll use the proper `\texorpdfstring` solution. However, I couldn't get the `silence` working, its not filtering the relevant warning. If I use `\WarningsOff` it does filter out all warning though, so maybe I am doing something wrong. I'll anyway accept your answer, as the `silence` package seems the way to go (with respect to the original question).

Comment: @Rabarberski It is hard to determine why you cannot filter the warning message without an MWE. Maybe it is due to loading the `silence` package after the `hyperref` package.

Comment: @maetra: yes, I agree. The point I wanted to make is that there is probably something I am doing wrong, but I don't care at this point, because I use the better solution to my problem (i.e. `\using texorpdfstring`). However, if I run the example in the post, the messages are filtered out (regardless of the string I put in there), but the messages end up in my PDF file!

Answer (score 4):

You can also cheat TeXnicCenter by removing the duplicate warnings from the LaTeX output. The latter can be done with a simple Perl script for example:

```perl
@lines = <STDIN>;
foreach (@lines) {
   if (/^(.*Warning:.*)$/) {
      next if ($warning{$1} == 1);
      $warning{$1} = 1;
   }
   print $_;
}
```

In order to apply the script, create the following batch file:

```
latex %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 | perl remove-warnings.pl
```

and tell TeXnicCenter to use this as the LaTeX executable (in the profile settings).

Without the filter script the message window looks like this:

[image]

Applying the script leads to this:

[image]

Comment: Nice general suggestion, but I don't have perl installed (and don't want to go through the trouble just for this)