# Disable warning from mdframed

Tags: mdframed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to avoid repetitive compiler warning messages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54344/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-repetitive-compiler-warning-messages)

When debugging some stuff I sometimes have empty mdframes and I get the log file littered with tons of

"Package mdframed Warning: You got a bad break"

How can I disable this message for mdframed only? (I still need warnings/errors from other packages)

Comment: The `silence` package as used [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54355/14100) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Scott H. suggests in a comment you can use the [`silence`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/silence/silence-doc.pdf) package for this purpose. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{silence}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\WarningFilter{mdframed}{You got a bad break}

\makeatletter

\mdf@PackageWarning{You got a bad break\MessageBreak
  because the last split box is empty\MessageBreak
  You have to change the settings}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `mdframed` package uses

```
\newcommand*\mdf@PackageWarning[1]{\PackageWarning{\mdframedpackagename}{#1}}
```

to report warning messages. So, to disable *all* warning messages from `mdframed`, you could redefine this in your preamble (*after* loading the `mdframed` package) to ignore the message:

```
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\mdf@PackageWarning[1]{}
\makeatother
```

### Notes:

- As Marco Daniel commented, this kind of solution is generally not a good idea as it will eliminate *all* warning message form the `mdframed` package. So if you want to eliminate just one message it is better to use the `silence` package as per the other answer.

### References:

- [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

Comment: I think it's not a good idea ;-)